# What purpose does the name of an ActorSystem serve?

Tags: akka

I'm just getting started with akka and don't understand what purpose the ActorSystem name serves.

To run multiple actor systems in the same JVM or host (which need to be remotely accessible), they anyway need to run on different ports.

akka.tcp://MySystem2@127.0.0.1:22222/user/greeter
akka.tcp://MySystem3@127.0.0.1:33333/user/greeter

Since the port number is part of the addressing scheme, why have the actor system name too in the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of akka remoting, yes, the port would serve as a differentiator, but not all systems use remoting; it's an add on.  The core actor library w/o remoting enabled needs to be able to support the concept of the an actor being deployed into two separate actor systems within the same JVM under the same path and with the same name and be able to differentiate them and that's where the actor system's name comes into play.  Let's say that this actor does some logging.  If you had two separate actor systems running in the same JVM, how would you differentiate which instance (the one deployed into system1 or the one deployed into system2) is the one producing the log messages?  By including the actor system's name in the fully qualified path, you will be able to differentiate which is which.

This is a simple example of the need for name and I'm sure people can some up with others.  But thinking about it from the remoting perspective is not the right way to think of things.  Remoting, as I mentioned earlier, is an add-on and is built on top of the core library.  The core library needs this differentiation and remoting just inherits it even if it seems unnecessary.

Comment: I'd also add that there's a reason humans have names and not just only addresses or UUIDs. Sometimes it's just easier to talk about "system3" instead of "194.256.119.4:4000"